# DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG resulting from C++AMP method

Tags: c++, directx, gpgpu, c++-amp

I am trying to implement a function which calculates the weightings and abscissae for the Gauss-Laguerre numerical integration method using C++AMP to parallelize the process and when running it I am getting a `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG` error.

This is my helper method for computing the logarithm of the gamma function on the GPU:

```
template <typename T>
T gammaln_fast( T tArg ) restrict( amp )
{
    const T tCoefficients[] = { T( 57.1562356658629235f ), T( -59.5979603554754912f ),
        T( 14.1360979747417471f ), T( -0.491913816097620199f ), T( 0.339946499848118887E-4f ),
        T( 0.465236289270485756E-4f ), T( -0.983744753048795646E-4f ), T( 0.158088703224912494E-3f ),
        T( -0.210264441724104883E-3f ), T( 0.217439618115212643E-3f ), T( -0.164318106536763890E-3f ),
        T( 0.844182239838527433E-4f ), T( -0.261908384015814087E-4f ), T( 0.386991826595316234E-5f ) };

    T y = tArg, tTemp = tArg + T( 5.2421875f );
    tTemp = (tArg + T( 0.5f )) * concurrency::fast_math::log( tTemp ) - tTemp;

    T tSer = T( 0.999999999999997092f );

    for( std::size_t s = 0; s < (sizeof( tCoefficients ) / sizeof( T )); ++s )
    {
        tSer += tCoefficients[s] / ++y;
    }

    return tTemp + concurrency::fast_math::log( T( 2.5066282746310005f ) * tSer / tArg );
}
```

And here is my function which computes the weights and abscissae:

```
template <typename T>
ArrayPair<T> CalculateGaussLaguerreWeights_fast( const T tExponent, const std::size_t sNumPoints, T tEps = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() )
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "You can only instantiate this function with a floating point data type");
    static_assert(!std::is_same<T, long double>::value, "You can not instantiate this function with long double type"); // The long double type is not currently supported by C++AMP

    T tCurrentGuess, tFatherGuess, tGrandFatherGuess;
    std::vector<T> vecInitialGuesses( sNumPoints );
    for( std::size_t s = 0; s < sNumPoints; ++s )
    {
        if( s == 0 )
        {
            tCurrentGuess = (T( 1.0f ) + tExponent) * (T( 3.0f ) + T( 0.92f ) * tExponent) / (T( 1.0f ) + T( 2.4f ) * sNumPoints + T( 1.8f ) * tExponent);
        }
        else if( s == 1 )
        {
            tFatherGuess = tCurrentGuess;
            tCurrentGuess += (T( 15.0f ) + T( 6.25f ) * tExponent) / (T( 1.0f ) + T( 0.9f ) * tExponent + T( 2.5f ) * sNumPoints);
        }
        else
        {
            tGrandFatherGuess = tFatherGuess;
            tFatherGuess = tCurrentGuess;
            std::size_t sDec = s - 1U;
            tCurrentGuess += ((T( 1.0f ) + T( 2.55f ) * sDec) / (T( 1.9f ) * sDec) + T( 1.26f ) * sDec * tExponent
                / (T( 1.0f ) + T( 3.5f ) * sDec)) * (tCurrentGuess - tGrandFatherGuess) / (T( 1.0f ) + T( 0.3f ) * tExponent);
        }
        vecInitialGuesses[s] = tCurrentGuess;
    }

    concurrency::array<T> arrWeights( sNumPoints ), arrAbsciasses( sNumPoints, std::begin(vecInitialGuesses) );

    try {
        concurrency::parallel_for_each( arrAbsciasses.extent, [=, &arrAbsciasses, &arrWeights]( concurrency::index<1> index ) restrict( amp ) {
            T tVal = arrAbsciasses[index], tIntermediate;
            T tPolynomial1 = T( 1.0f ), tPolynomial2 = T( 0.0f ), tPolynomial3, tDerivative;
            std::size_t sIterationNum = 0;
            do {
                tPolynomial1 = T( 1.0f ), tPolynomial2 = T( 0.0f );

                for( std::size_t s = 0; s < sNumPoints; ++s )
                {
                    tPolynomial3 = tPolynomial2;
                    tPolynomial2 = tPolynomial1;
                    tPolynomial1 = ((2 * s + 1 + tExponent - tVal) * tPolynomial2 - (s + tExponent) * tPolynomial3) / (s + 1);
                }

                tDerivative = (sNumPoints * tPolynomial1 - (sNumPoints + tExponent) * tPolynomial2) / tVal;
                tIntermediate = tVal;
                tVal = tIntermediate - tPolynomial1 / tDerivative;
                ++sIterationNum;

            } while( concurrency::fast_math::fabs( tVal - tIntermediate ) > tEps || sIterationNum < 10 );

            arrAbsciasses[index] = tVal;
            arrWeights[index] = -concurrency::fast_math::exp( gammaln_fast( tExponent + sNumPoints ) - gammaln_fast( T( sNumPoints ) ) ) / (tDerivative * sNumPoints * tPolynomial2);
        } );
    }
    catch( concurrency::runtime_exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << "Runtime error, code: " << e.get_error_code() << "; message: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return std::make_pair( std::move( arrAbsciasses ), std::move( arrWeights ) );
}
```

And here is the full trace from the debug console:

> D3D11: Removing Device.
>   D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::RemoveDevice: Device removal has been triggered for the following reason (DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG: The Device took an unreasonable amount of time to execute its commands, or the hardware crashed/hung. As a result, the TDR (Timeout Detection and Recovery) mechanism has been triggered. The current Device Context was executing commands when the hang occurred. The application may want to respawn and fallback to less aggressive use of the display hardware). [ EXECUTION ERROR #378: DEVICE_REMOVAL_PROCESS_AT_FAULT]
>   D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Map: Returning DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED, when a Resource was trying to be mapped with READ or READWRITE. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #2097214: RESOURCE_MAP_DEVICEREMOVED_RETURN]

My apologies for not being able to produce a small reproducible example; I hope that this is still an acceptable question, as I am unable to solve this by myself.

Answer (score 3):

When using DirectCompute, the main challenge is to write computations that do not run afoul of the Direct3D automatic 'GPU hang' detection timeout. By default, the system assumes if a shader is taking more than a few seconds, the GPU is actually hung. This heuristic works for visual shaders, but you can easily create a DirectCompute shader that takes a long time to complete.

The solution is to disable the timeout detection. You can do this by creating the Direct3D 11 device with `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT` See [Disabling TDR on Windows 8 for your C++ AMP algorithms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/03/06/disabling-tdr-on-windows-8-for-your-c-amp-algorithms.aspx) blog post. The main thing to remember is that `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT` requires the DirectX 11.1 or later runtime which is included with Windows 8.x and can be installed on Windows 7 Service Pack 1 with KB[2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838). See [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/14/directx-11-1-and-windows-7.aspx), [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx), and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863687.aspx) for some caveats of using KB2670838.